# Why my Go program creates another Go process with the name of an open file, and why it's so big?

Tags: file, go, process, executable, ram

I have a big .json file that has about 2mb. I'm using [this code](http://www.chazzuka.com/2015/03/load-parse-json-file-golang/) to read the json, with a little modification:

```
func main() {
    pages := getPages()
    for {

    }
    for _, p := range pages {
       fmt.Println(p.toString())
    }
```

As you can see, I've put an infinite loop so I could make the program wait while I read the process's RAM size. When I've gone to read it, I've found 2 go programs running. I just did

`go run myfile.go`

but then I got 2 binaries: one named `go`, and the other with the name of the file without the json part. The `go` binary has like 5mb, but this one has 36mb...

Why does go creates another process with the name of the file? Is it where it holds the file so I can read? Why it does that? As far as I know, the file reading should be handed by the OS. And why it's so big compared to the .json size?

Also, shouldn't, when `getPages()` return, both the file object and json object be deleted from memory because of the go's garbage collector?

Comment: The infinite loop without sleep or any is a bad idea it consumes a lot of CPU. Is the file pointed by URL the exact code you are using?

Comment: It would be difficult to help you  unless you respond to comments

Comment: but then I got 2 binaries: one named go, and the other with the name of the file without the json part. The go binary has like 5mb, but this one has 36mb...

`go run` does not create binaries in working directory

Answer (score 4):

> Why does go creates another process with the name of the file?

It doesn't. You did. When you do `go run main.go` You are running the go program which compiles your main.go to a different executable (you remember that Go is a compiled language producing native executables?) and executes this second executable. You told the go tool to do so and it behaves as told. If you do not like that: `go build -o whatever; ./whatever`.

> Also, shouldn't, when getPages() return, both the file object and json object be deleted from memory because of the go's garbage collector?

Yes and that actually happens. It just isn't observable in the way you tried to check it. Memory management in Go is complicated and the interplay with the memory management of the OS is complicated (and OS dependent) and OS memory management is complicated too.

Very roughly: The unreferenced objects are collected by the Go GC but that memory is not "returned" to the OS as "returning" and "re-acquire" memory from the OS is a very expensive operation, so memory is not "returned" to the OS (unless needed).

Search SO or the web for "go does not release memory" if you think the gory details of memory management are of interest to you.